# Java - How to parse irc message to human readable

Tags: java, irc

I am creating an irc client in Java. It work fine but the message from the server is a bit "messed-up"
for example `:User1!webirc@1.9.com PRIVMSG #channel :test`. So i wanna know how to parse the irc message to human readable? Here is a regex that i found `^(:(\\S+) )?(\\S+)( (?!:)(.+?))?( :(.+))?$` for irc message.

Comment: The IRC protocol is already human readable.

Answer (score 2):

The IRC Protocol is documented here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812

> 2.3.1 Message format in Augmented BNF

> The protocol messages must be extracted from the contiguous stream of
> octets.  The current solution is to designate two characters, CR and
> LF, as message separators.  Empty messages are silently ignored,
> which permits use of the sequence CR-LF between messages without
> extra problems.

> The extracted message is parsed into the components ,
>  and list of parameters ().

```
The Augmented BNF representation for this is:

message    =  [ ":" prefix SPACE ] command [ params ] crlf
prefix     =  servername / ( nickname [ [ "!" user ] "@" host ] )
command    =  1*letter / 3digit
params     =  *14( SPACE middle ) [ SPACE ":" trailing ]
           =/ 14( SPACE middle ) [ SPACE [ ":" ] trailing ]

nospcrlfcl =  %x01-09 / %x0B-0C / %x0E-1F / %x21-39 / %x3B-FF
                ; any octet except NUL, CR, LF, " " and ":"
middle     =  nospcrlfcl *( ":" / nospcrlfcl )
trailing   =  *( ":" / " " / nospcrlfcl )

SPACE      =  %x20        ; space character
crlf       =  %x0D %x0A   ; "carriage return" "linefeed"
```

Comment: xD then how to make it human-readable? Read my question properly

Comment: I did read the question properly. The only correct way to do what you want to do is by understanding the protocol and extracting the relevant parts knowing what they mean. If you want a decent result you can't just throw everything away, it's there because it means something. All the information you need to do that is in my answer, I'm not going to write your code for you though.

Comment: still doesn't answer the question. if somebody asks you how to open a bottle, you don't give him a specification of a screw thread